# VMware Workstation Pro 12 - Unstable when Ubuntu 16.04 VM is moved machine with 4k Display

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, 4k-monitor

**Note:** *Due to my reputation, I am unable to post images.*

I am experiencing issues with my Ubuntu VM being unstable. The OS GUI crashes when I open the "start" menu on Ubuntu. I also get occasional strange graphical artifacts. I believe it's because the machine I copied the VM to has a 4K display.

When I first copied over the VM from my Desktop, I found out that Ubuntu didn't scale the text at all for my high resolution. By using the command line I opened the display configuration and enabled text scaling. However, my start menu was still ridiculously slow to open. I found out that VT-x wasn't enabled so I went ahead and enabled that and restarted the VM. The issues still persist.

tl;dr
I moved my Ubuntu 16.04 VM to a different machine with a high resolution display, now it's unstable.

Comment: So I forced the VM to Intel VT-x/EPT and it fixed the performance issues; however I'm still getting -horrible- artifacting issues. http://i.imgur.com/67C0Xdz.jpg

Comment: As a temporary solution I switched to gnome